# Internal Error + crashing with Intellij IDEA 2016.2 whenever I start a Symfony Project on MacOSX Sierra

Tags: php, symfony, intellij-idea

For two days now, I got an internal Error whenever I launch my Symfony project with Intellij IDEA followed by a crash and a shut down and it becomes impossible to work.

I tried to delete all Symfony plugins, but the issues remain.

Here is the error log :

[image]

```
Exception Name: JavaNativeException
```

Description: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility.getAccessibleIndexInParent(CAccessibility.java:287)

User Info: (null)

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3f677bb **exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffe86d4a2a objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3f67709 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   JavaNativeFoundation                0x0000000102fef64d JNFCallStaticIntMethod + 236
4   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x0000000109cf2cef +[JavaComponentAccessibility createWithAccessible:withEnv:withView:] + 76
5   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x0000000109cf320f -[JavaComponentAccessibility accessibilityFocusedUIElement] + 194
6   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x0000000109cc834e -[AWTView accessibilityFocusedUIElement] + 156
7   AppKit                              0x00007fffd23ad417 -[NSWindow(NSWindowAccessibility) accessibilityFocusedUIElement] + 124
8   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x0000000109cf2f6d +[JavaComponentAccessibility postFocusChanged:] + 96
9   Foundation                          0x00007fffd5949f2a __NSThreadPerformPerform + 326
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3efe581 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3edf98c **CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3edee76 __CFRunLoopRun + 934
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3ede874 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffd347ef6c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffd347eda1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fffd347ebd6 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
17  AppKit                              0x00007fffd1b755f5 _DPSNextEvent + 1093
18  AppKit                              0x00007fffd22858eb -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1637
19  libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000109d7a41a -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
20  AppKit                              0x00007fffd1b69fbd -[NSApplication run] + 926
21  libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000109d7a22e +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
22  libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x0000000109d073b7 -[AWTStarter starter:] + 905
23  Foundation                          0x00007fffd5949f2a __NSThreadPerformPerform + 326
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3efe581 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3edf98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3edee76 __CFRunLoopRun + 934
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd3ede874 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
28  idea                                0x00000001000013bf main + 357
29  idea                                0x0000000100001238 start + 52

I don't know what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this only happen with one specific Symfony project?
Deleting the `.idea` folder (inside the project) could help.

Comment: Hi ! I just reinstalled Intellij IDEA and now everything works great !